# Show that Knapsack-like problem on directed graph is NP-hard

Tags: complexity-theory, graphs, np-hard

Let $G=(V,A)$ represent a directed acyclic graph, where a value $v_i \ge 0$ is assigned to every vertex $u_i$. Let $T$ represent a threshold and $N = |V|$. Problem statement:

maximize: $\sum_{i=1}^{N}v_i x_i$

subject to: $\sum_{i=1}^{N} x_i \leq T$ and $x_i \in \lbrace 0,1 \rbrace$

and $x_i(x_j-1) = 0 \quad \forall a\in A: u_i \to u_j$

In other words, we want to choose up to $T$ vertices that maximize the sum of their values, with the restriction that if a vertex $u_i$ is chosen, any reachable vertices $u_j$ must also be chosen. Therefore, $x_i(x_j-1) = 0$ for a given arc $u_i \to u_j$ represents that if $u_i$ is chosen ($x_i = 1$) then $u_j$ must be chosen as well ($x_j = 1$).

I want to prove that this is a **NP-hard** problem. To do that, I have taken the 0-1 knapsack problem, which is NP-hard:

maximize: $\sum_{i=1}^{M}v_i x_i$

subject to: $\sum_{i=1}^{M} w_i x_i \leq T$ and $x_i \in \lbrace 0,1 \rbrace$

The 0-1 knapsack may be reduced to an *instance* of the original problem. Assume an instance of the original problem, with the following properties of $G$:

- $v_i = 0$ for every vertex $u_i$ with incoming arcs.
- All vertices have at most 1 incoming arc.

The 0-1 knapsack may be reduced to this instance by the following polynomial transformation:

- There are $M$ items, where $M$ is the number of vertices $u_i \in G: v_i > 0$.
- The value $v_i$ of each item the value $v_i$ of vertex $u_i$.
- The weight $w_i$ of each item is $1+$ the number of reachable vertices from $u_i$.

Explanation:

- Since vertices with a non-zero value have no incoming arcs, they may be chosen independently, as there is no possibility for such a vertice to be chosen twice, as a "dependency" of another one. Thus, individual items in the knapsack problem may be mapped to these vertices.
- As no vertice has more than 1 incoming arc, no vertice may be reached by multiple vertices. This guarantees that the weights of each knapsack item are independent of each other.

**Questions**

1. Have I formulated the original problem correctly, using the mathematical notations? It's been quite some time since I have formally formulated a graph theory problem.
2. Is this reduction enough to prove that the original problem is NP-hard? I only have reduced the 0-1 knapsack only to an **instance** of the original problem, not the original problem itself. Does this imply that the original problem is "at least as hard, if not harder" than the 0-1 knapsack?
3. Assuming that question (2) stands, is my reduction correct?
4. Alternatively, could I demonstrate my case via another reduction?

Answer (score -1):

$x_i \leq x_j \forall (i,j) \in A$ is a linear constraint that represents your requirement (if $x_i=1$ it would push $x_j$ to take value $1$ as well). You get a constrained knapsack problem. You can easily reduce a knapsack to it by considering a graph that simply has no arrows.

Comment: A graph with no arcs can be solved in $\mathcal{O}(N)$, as it's enough to find the $T^{th}$ "heaviest" vertex and choose this and all heavier ones. It's essentially the 0-1 knapsack with all weights being $w_i = 1$. Note that the "weight" in the original problem is the number of "dependent" vertices that have to be chosen, as well. Am I missing something? (Thanks for the notation)

Comment: I don't think your idea for a reduction works.  Knapsack has both value and weight for each item; this problem has only value, but no weight.  I don't see how you propose to encode the weights of the items in the knapsack problem.  If you think the reduction works, I encourage you to edit the answer to show the proposed reduction explicitly.  (Cc: @Adama -- no, I don't think you're missing anything.)